# Powershell script only works on one machine. Function return object handling

Tags: arrays, powershell, object

I have a script I use to manage some Exchange attributes. I recently added some code to handle setting proxy addresses. I use a function to build the list then return a collection object to set the list in a different function. this is the jist of that function:

```
function buildProxyAddresses([string]$user)
{
    $addressCollection = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection

    $addressCollection.Add("smtp:" + $user + $domain)
    #etc
    #etc....

    Return @(,$addressCollection)
}#endFunc buildProxyAddresses
```

Took me a while but I figured out how to pass the object by sticking it in array when I return it, ugly but functional. works fine, I can access the object by calling a `$returnvar.item(3)` on the return variable. where the third element is the `ADPropertyValueCollection`

Now I take the same script to my Co-Workers computer and he runs it and he gets an error that tells him :

> [System.Object[]] doesn't contain a method named 'item'.

I have no idea why it runs different on his machine

Comment: Have you tried using `$returnvar[3]` instead?

Comment: I haven't He's not around at the moment so I can't test on his computer right now. 

though if that does work I'd like to know why his machine returns a different type of array lacking the item() method.

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
$returnvar[3]
```

It's likely its failing on a machine that's running an older version of powershell. Looks like the `.item(x)` syntax works from version 3 upwards.

However, it's not a normal way to reference an array index, the standard is to use `$array[idx]`

Comment: I think this is it, thought we had all the same install but he's using 2 and I'm on V4.  I was using Item() since originally I was just working with the collection object, i don't think the collection supports []